# Last-modified в Yii2 не могу разобраться в документации

Tags: yii2

Необходимо на всех страницах категорий и товаров установить заголовок last-modified  в фреймворке Yii2.

В документации нашел код и описание, но не совсем понял куда его вставить и как настроить чтобы на всех страницах работало.

Я еще постигаю азы Yii2 не судите строго.

Ниже код из документации, подскажите по адаптации

```
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\filters\HttpCache',
                'only' => ['view'],
                'etagSeed' => function ($action, $params) {
                    $post = $this->findModel(\Yii::$app->request->get('id'));
                    return serialize([$post->title, $post->content]);
                },
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

behaviors  вставляется в котроллер

у меня примерно так

```
public function behaviors() {
    return [
        'HttpCache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\filters\HttpCache',
            'lastModified' => function ($action, $params) {

                $model = \app\models\Products::findOne($_GET['id']);
                $time = (empty($model->time_edit))?$model->time_add:$model->time_edit;

                return $time;
            },
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: 1. Если у меня много категорий на странице а не только product? ,То как это прописать. 2. И time_add и time_edit это какие то встроенные методы?

Comment: $action - это экшен в вашем контроллере. можете на его основе выбрать нужную модель.
2- time_add и time_edit это время создания и редактирования товара в моем случае. взяты из базы. в вашем можете выводить какую-то другую дату.